# Magento2 REST API PRODUCTS "category_links" updates

Tags: magento2, rest-api

When I update a prodcut using POST with product ID the "category_links" get updated to. When a product was before in category 1 and now I want it to be in 2 and I post like this

```
"category_links": [
            {   "position": 0,  "category_id": "2"}
        ]
```

The product is afterwards in both categories.
The only way would be to post first with

```
[]
```

and then again with

```
"category_id": "2"
```

Is there any trick to avoid a second POST?

Comment: I know it's ages ago, but did you find a solution? I am stumbling on this exact problem right now